# I need to create such a table in HTML Without the use of CSS [I am attaching a picture]

Tags: html

[Table Prtscn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnR4L.png)

I need to create such a table in HTML Without the use of CSS
I have been trying for several hours to create this table, but without success, Would appreciate help :)

I enclose the code I was working on.
I am attaching a picture

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <table border="1"width="400">
            <tr>
        <td>Hello world</td>
       

        <table border="1"width="400">
            
                
        <td>
            <table border="2" cellpadding="1"celspaceing="2">
                
                    <tr>
                        <td>A</td>
                        <td>A</td>
                        <td>A</td>
                    </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>E</td>
                <td>F</td>
                <td>G</td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        
        </table>
       
            <td>Cell B</td>
            <td>Cell C</td>
       
               
       
    
    
            </table>
       
                  <tr>
                    <table border="1"width="400">
            
                        <td>Hi There</td>
                  </tr>
        
     
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what’s driving the requirement not to use CSS? Does this include inline styles? Or just external stylesheets?

Comment: They only wanted to use html, without CSS

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because the term "CSS" can be a bit confusing here. There are technical reasons why some projects may not be able to support _external_ CSS files. But the community is interpreting this to mean that you can still use e.g. CSS within a `style` attribute. But if that's not true, you probably want to clarify that, as otherwise these answers aren't going to satisfy your requirements.

Comment: He asked not to use either internal or external CSS, which is why I got so entangled

Comment: You should really go talk with your teacher. CSS should be used instead of styling HTML tags, which are obsolete, by the way.

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE: Meh. It's an assignment. We don't know how it fits into the instructor's overall curriculum. I think understanding what can and cannot be done with markup, and how much it clutters the code, can be a useful foundation for appreciating the usefulness and flexibility of CSS. Obviously, if that's _all_ that's being taught, that's an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is this?

```
<table border="1" width="350px" cellpadding="5px">
<tr>
    <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><table>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <font size="5">
                <table border ="2" >
                        <tr>
                        <td>A</td>
                        <td>B</td>
                        <td>C</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>D</td>
                        <td>E</td>
                        <td>F</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </font>
    </td>
            <td><table cellspacing="20px"><tr><td></td></tr></table></td>
            <td><table cellspacing="20px"><tr><td></td></tr></table></td>
            <td><table cellspacing="20px"><tr><td>text</td></tr></table></td>
            <td><table cellspacing="20px"><tr><td>text</td></tr></table></td>
        </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            text
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow, that's almost perfect.
It remains to change the BORDER that will be similar to this (I attach a link to a screenshot) ↓
https://prnt.sc/1ylho9l

Comment: The original screenshot you posted was different. I have edited the code for the new screenshot.

Comment: Is it possible to use colspan?
If so I would be very happy ... I was asked to use with colspan.

Thank you :)

Comment: Eek. <font> is obsolete.

Answer (score -1):

The effect can be achieved by nesting a table:

```css
tr{
  border:1px solid;
}

table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
#nested td{
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td colspan="3">text</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id="nested">
        <tr>
          <td>a</td>
          <td>b</td>
          <td>c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>d</td>
          <td>e</td>
          <td>f</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan="3">text</td></tr>
</table>
```

With inline styles only (as per OP request):

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tbody><tr style="border: 1px solid;"><td colspan="3">text</td></tr>
  <tr style="border: 1px solid;">
    <td>
      <table id="nested" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tbody><tr style="border: 1px solid;">
          <td style="border: 1px solid;">a</td>
          <td style="border: 1px solid;">b</td>
          <td style="border: 1px solid;">c</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border: 1px solid;">
          <td style="border: 1px solid;">d</td>
          <td style="border: 1px solid;">e</td>
          <td style="border: 1px solid;">f</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody></table>
    </td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="border: 1px solid;"><td colspan="3">text</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: I appreciate very much, but asked without css :(

Comment: @OmryBiton Why can't you use CSS? It will make it much more complicated if you don't.

Comment: So asked, not to use CSS :(

Comment: @OmryBiton I mean, if you don't use CSS, you will make it much more complicated.

Comment: At the request of the teacher, I am not allowed to use css

Comment: @OmryBiton OK. I've updated my answer to include an inline-style only version.

Comment: Dear Spectric.
I thank you very much, it's not obvious.
But unfortunately my teacher asked without using style